# in vscode for mix unit test, how to use `--only` parameter?

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir

The  purpose is to debug only one unit test in the `exs` file, therefore it is necessary to ignore other unit tests in the same `exs` file.

My previous solution is comment out the other unit test, but the bad side of this solution is I can't find other unit tests easily through vscode's outline view as follows:

[image]

From the [mix doc](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/1.12/Mix.Tasks.Test.html), it is found that mix command has `--include` and `--only` option.

I have adjusted `launch.json` file as follows, update task args as `--trace --only :external`, and update the `exs` file, but when runing `mix test`, it gives the error message.

[image]

[image]

```
Remember to keep good posture and stay hydrated!
helloworld
(Debugger) Task failed because an exception was raised:
    ** (Mix.Error) Could not invoke task "test": 1 error found!
--trace --only :external : Unknown option
        (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix.ex:515: Mix.raise/2
        (elixir_ls_debugger 0.10.0) lib/debugger/server.ex:1119: ElixirLS.Debugger.Server.launch_task/2
```

Then I changed launch.json to `"--trace --only :external"`, similar error message as follows:

```
(Debugger) Task failed because an exception was raised:
    ** (Mix.Error) Could not invoke task "test": 1 error found!
--trace --only :external : Unknown option
        (mix 1.13.4) lib/mix.ex:515: Mix.raise/2
        (elixir_ls_debugger 0.10.0) lib/debugger/server.ex:1119: ElixirLS.Debugger.Server.launch_task/2
```

Comment: I think you should remove the `:` from the tag atom in the command line: does `mix test --trace --only external` work?

Comment: I have tried no ":", the same result and pasted the message as above.

Comment: Did you try using the line number? Like: `mix test test/my_test.exs:34`. That will run only the test on line 34.

Comment: @zwippie It works by terminal command, but doesn't work in vscode `launch.json` file, it gives error message "Paths given to "mix test" did not match any directory/file: ./test/inventory_map_test.exs.exs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by syntax problem. Every paremeter should be one element as follows:

```
    "taskArgs": [
        "--trace", "--warnings-as-errors", "--only", "external"
    ],
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use a plugin called [Elixir Test](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samuel-pordeus.elixir-test). It has a few nice features including what you are asking for.

To run a single test place your cursor within the code of the test, then select "Elixir Test: Run test at cursor" from the command palette.

Another helpful command is: "Elixir Test: Jump". If you are editing a module file, this command will jump to the test file corresponding to the module. It will optionally create the skeleton for the test file if you haven't created it yet.

[image: Commands for Elixir Test]

Comment: It can be used but it is a little slow because I have to jump to the related the test file and move cursor to the related unit test.